# Actionbarsherlock FragmentTabPager: How to get the notified on tab selection?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am new to android fragments. I am using actionbarsherlock FragmentsTabsPager. I have three tabs containing three fragments. All of three fragments can be viewed by selecting tabs or with swipe. I want to get notified every time tab(fragment) is selected. I want to reload the listview in listfragment every time it is selected/reselected either by swipe of clicking on tab. How can I do this? Do we have any callback in fragments. OncreateView, onactivitycreated not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is a good solution...

Listener:

```
    public interface OnShowFragmentListener {
        abstract public void onShow();
    }
```

In your tabs adapter:

```
    private OnShowFragmentListener onShowSearchScreenListener = new OnShowFragmentListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow() {
        }
    };

    public void setOnShowFragmentListener(OnShowFragmentListener onShowFragmentListener) {
        this.onShowFragmentListener = onShowFragmentListener;
    }     

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        if (position == 0) {
            onShowFragmentListener.onShow();
        }
    }
```

And in onCreate() of your tab fragment:

```
    MainTabsPager main = (MainTabsPager) getActivity();
    main.setOnShowFragmentListener(new MainTabsPager.OnShowFragmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            updateFragment();
        }
    });
```